# Is it possible to use standatd css libraries/frameworks in pyside/kivy?

Tags: pyside, kivy

I'd like to make a gui application with python. I've found a majority support for PySide and Kivy, so I've mentioned them. I'll be glad to know if there are better suggestions too. My question is that there any means of using say bootstrap css into these GUI frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PySide, you could do it(only to some extent), with a handy trick. Take the css file of BootStrap framework and modify the elements in it to match PySide elements. For example, the button entry in bootstrap should be made Qbutton. After this modification, use this stylesheet in either code or in QtDesigner.

Comment: Thank you, It worked for QButton, I'll surely try it for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This actually would be a great opportunity for a translation tool between CSS and Kivy styling.  I know from personal experience that the only reason I'm still using PhoneGap instead of Kivy is because CSS is just so simple to get a grip onto.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that there any means of using say bootstrap css into these GUI frameworks?

Not with kivy, it's not a web framework, though it has its own kv language for defining widget trees in a more convenient way than pure python.

(You can use a webview or web widget I suppose, but we have no cross-platform solution for this right now, and you'd lose the benefits of kivy anyway).

Comment: But using webview only themes what's in html right? what about when I use qbuttons and all?

Comment: I don't know anything about qbuttons, I'm talking about kivy. For which you can theme buttons in a range of ways, but most conveniently using kv language